# how i can use django context inside context

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

Well I know that what I'm doing is not very feasible, but I wanted to know if there's any way to do this.I want to create a portfolio blog to post some 3d renders, for that I want to have more control over the structure of the page. for this I created two models (one for the post and another to receive the images, linking them to the post through a foreign key) so that I could have an indefinite number of images, the problem came when I decided that I wanted to be able to choose the one positioning of the images according to my need/desire, for that I did the following:

I used django summernote temporarily to be able to test the written posts, I knew that it would probably not be possible to do this because the content sent from the models is static.

I have the following models:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    titulo_post=models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Titulo')
    autor_post=models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, verbose_name='autor')
    data_post=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, verbose_name='Data publicação')
    conteudo_post =models.TextField()
    publicado_post=models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Status publicação')

    def __str__(self) :
        return self.titulo_post
```

and:

```
class Estudo(models.Model):
    imagem=models.ImageField(upload_to='estd_img/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True,  null=True)
    post=models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I tried to put the following value in the field "conteudo_post" through the administrative area to  see if it would work

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-10 mx-auto">
      <img class="img-fluid " src="{{imagem.0.url}}" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
```

as I thought it didn't work,  when I use `{{post_conteudo}}` the rendered html displays an escaped version of the content, when I use {{post_conteudo |safe}} it creates the image container, but is not able to find it. when checking the browser's developer mode I can see that the value of `{{image.0.url}}` was not processed and it remains in that format in the final html